# epson javapos adk linux compile error

Tags: epson, adk, javapos

i am working on a company and we are trying to create an java app for epsons thermal printer.
the problem is that we get an error when we try to compile ur project.
the error is:

```
error code 111
jpos.JposException: Failed to load the JNI.
    at jp.co.epson.upos.T88V.pntr.T88VService.initializeUsingCommand(T88VService.java:1278)
    at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.open(CommonPrinterService.java:1300)
    at jpos.BaseJposControl.open(Unknown Source)
    at printersample_step4.Step4Frame.processWindowEvent(Step4Frame.java:92)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2013)
```

what does the JNI error mean?is it a problem about my jvm?or is it cause the epson lib?

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem.
the problems was the LD_LIBRARY_PATH
i set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the bin files from epson then it compile my codes correctly.